# Ordenar usuarios por características de un modelo relacionado en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un modelo de usuarios y tengo un modelo de suscripciones con una relación has_one. Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente y no entiendo cómo hacerlo. Lo que quiero lograr es que en la vista de índice de usuarios, los usuarios Premium se enumeran primero y luego se enumeran el resto de los usuarios. Estoy usando la gema Pagy para la paginación y la gema de saqueo para las búsquedas. Entonces les dejo el codigo:

**Modelo User:**

```
has_one :suscription, dependent: :destroy
```

**Modelo Subscription:**

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  enum status: {
    free:     0,
    premium:  1
  }
end
```

**User Controller:**

```
def index
        @q = User.includes(:profile).ransack(params[:q])
        @pagy, @users = pagy(User.order(created_at: :asc).ransack(params[:q]).result(distinct: true), items:12)
    end
```

Comment: Supongo con "gema de saqueo" te refieres a ransack que lo pasaste por traductor automático por alguna razón... en fin, si quieres los usuarios premium primero, ordena la búsqueda por status `User.order(status: :desc)`.

Comment: si, es esa gema, ya he intentado eso pero no me funciona

Comment: Entonces tu problema debe ser algo más, pero con la información que entregas no es suficiente para saber. Quizás el estado no se está guardando, o que tengas un default_scope. Revisa en los logs del server cual es la consulta específica que estás haciendo a la tabla de users y agrégala a tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias por responder. la columna status no está en la tabla Users, está en una tabla Subscription que tiene una relacion uno a uno con User, y de esta forma: User.order(status: :desc) no puedo acceder a ordenar.

Comment: Asumiendo que la tabla para `Subscription` es `subscriptions`: `User.joins(:subscription).order("subscriptions.id DESC")`.

Comment: Ahh mi error, no me había fijado que era una tabla aparte. Creo que la solución es similar a lo que puso Gerry, sería algo como `User.joins(:subscription).order("subscriptions.status DESC")`.

Comment: gracias por responder, ya había intentado con eso, parece que no se me iba a hacer complicado, pero no no estoy consiguiendo acceder al listado de esa forma. me aparece este error con el codigo que me sugeris: Mysql2::Error: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'myapp_development.suscriptions.status' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT